# Script runs slower in the dotnet WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, webbrowser-control, smooth-scrolling

I use the WebBrowser control and [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) in my winforms application to render a html marquee. I downloaded the sample and added

```
autoScrollingInterval: 3
```

to

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
});
```

to make it move faster. When I open the sample in IE it works just fine but when I use the WebBrowser control and call the navigate method the scroller moves much slower.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand it, the issue you are dealing with is a versioning issue with the WebBrowser Control rendering in IE 7 Standard Mode and the actual WebBrowser you are using in IE is either IE 8 or IE 9, and it works there, yet your JQuery/JavaScript or CSS inclusions are not working in IE 7.

Let me tell you this straight up. The default rendering engine on
    the webbrowser control is fixed to ensure compatibility across all
    platforms.

Basically, if you're installed browser is IE 7 - IE 9, then the
    rendering engine used is IE 7.0 only (by default).

If, however, your installed IE version is IE 6 or below, then the
    rendering engine used is IE 4.0 (not kidding), unless of course you
    set it otherwise.

There is a misconception that WebBrowser control uses whatever is
    currently installed (current IE version) but this is not true, since
    they do this to reduce backward compatibility issues. You can see
    (as proof) that this really is your problem by going to
    www.whatsmyuseragent.com in your normal browser, and then going to
    that website again in your WebBrowser control, you will see that it
    says MSIE 7.0 :).

You can set it to use the current installed version of internet
    explorer, either using a META tag in-page, or editing the Registry
    on the machine where the webbrowser control will run (editing for
    Current_User and Local_Machine will both work).

WebBrowser control will (normally) use whatever version of IE you
    have installed, but for compatibility reasons it will render pages
    in IE7 Standards mode by default.

If you want to take advantage of new IE9 features, you should add
    the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`
    inside the `<head>` tag of your HTML page.

This meta tag must be added before any links to CSS, JavaScript
    files etc that are also in your `<head>` to work properly though (only
    other `<meta>` tags or the `<title>` tag can come before it).

An alternative is to add a registry entry to:

> HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Internet Explorer > Main >
>   FeatureControl > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

And in there add 'YourCompiledApplicationName.exe' with value '9000' to
    force the WebBrowser control to display pages in IE9 mode. Though
    there are other values you can use too too, note that these docs
    aren't entirely accurate as it does not seem possible to get a page
    to render in IE 8 mode whatever value you use. (Note: YourCompiledApplicationName.exe must be the EXE file name that you compile which contains your WebBrowser Control, it will only work for the file name that you've included in the registry). Also, it wouldnt hurt to add vshost.exe and YourCompiledApplicationName.exe.svchost so it works when run through your IDE, and also, If your app is running under 64bit Windows, you likely should also set the following DWORD under the following registry path to the same value (as per the 32bit path):

> HK[LM|CU] \ SOFTWARE \ Wow6432Node \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Main \
>   FeatureControl \ FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Adding the registry key to the same path in HKCU instead of HKLM
    will also work - this is useful as writing to HKLM requires admin
    privileges where as HKCU does not.

Not sure if when IE 10.0 comes out if the WebBrowser controls
    default engine will go to 10.0 (if 10.0 is installed on system of
    course) or if it will remain as IE 7.0 even after IE 10.0 is
    released, we will have to see once it comes out. However, if we
    guess based on previous experience, i suspect IE 10.0 will be the
    last version that uses IE 7.0 rendering engine, and when IE 11 comes
    out, the default rendering engine will remain as IE 11 for all
    versions of IE between IE 11 & IE 14. This is just a guess by
    extrapolating what they've done in the past.

For more information on the values you can set the registry to,[check this out:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'll check it and post the results.

Comment: Reference for Browser Emulation values @  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx